# Hibernate Envers: how to get the revision_type information for a given revision and a given entity class

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate envers 3.6.3.Final.  I can audit table and I can see the `_audit` table is populated with the `revision_number`, `revision_type` and entity data.
 I am making a history page, where I want to display all revision entries, so that when user clicks a revision id, then I can display the entity data along with revision type i.e. it is added, deleted or modified. I am trying to use `AuditQuery`, but I am not sure how to get the `revision_type` information for a given revision and a given entity class. Is is possible to do in `AuditQuery` ?

I can get the 'RevisionType' info by writing Hibernate query. But I want to reuse any existing framework api for this.  In another way, I passed different 'RevisionType' as criteria to `AuditQuery`  (i.e. multiple query for DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE) and check if  I get any result, but this is not efficient way.

Comment: @Boris Stitnicky Any reason why this -ve vote ?

Comment: Because the questions should not be written as work orders. In other words, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth now. I had the same problem and were able to get the revision type by using the *AuditQueryCreator#forRevisionsOfEntity* method like this:

```
List<Object[]> resultList = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(entityClass, entityClass.getName(), false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(revision)).getResultList();
```

This return a list of array triplets of changes concerning the specified revision. The array triplet contains the entity, entity information and at last the revision type.

Be sure the set the *selectEntitiesOnly* argument of *AuditQueryCreator#forRevisionsOfEntity* to *false*. If set to  *true* the method will return list of entity objects only.

Hibernate Envers version 4.2.2 is used here.